# How to integrate microservices to asp.net framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, microservices

I have a application with a framework of asp.net(monolithic approach). How can i integrate that application with micro-services. How can i create a data eventual consistency and Modularity. Is it possible to integrate micro-services with monolithic or need to migrate to other framework. Can anybody help with this scenario.

Comment: Please give more details as to what are you trying to achieve, your question is really vague

Comment: @RiazRaza iam trying to migrate monolithic to micro-services. I have an application in monolithic approach is i wanted to recreate total application to microservices or i can  integrate microservices in monolithic? do you know microservices?

Comment: Azure Functions is exactly what you need

Comment: please rewrite your quesion and explain it better.  converting monolithic to microservices is totally different concept than integrating microservices and monolithic. from question it's hard to pick what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: the answer to this question can easily cover a few books worth of text. Might want to start something and come back with small and very specific issues.

Comment: @Imran iam trying  to convert application from monolithic to microservices.  I want to know basics steps. how can i going to acheive can you help with that. I think now u catch my point.

Comment: @charan this is a huge topic and it all depends on how you want to architect your application. There is not right answer but best practices. If you are not aware of micro-services architecture i would strongly recommend understand this before you actually start implementing. If you don't get it right , it could be a nightmare. With microservice architecture you have to choose your tech stack , data model and cloud services (if using any) wisely.